# Extracting and Updating XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML like this where I want to replace one of the element by checking its value at the bottom of the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employee>
      <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
      <LastName>Patil</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Email>tanmaypatil@xyz.com</Email>
      <AddressRef>0123321</AddressRef>

      <AllAddressRef>
        <AddressRef>
          <UniqueID>0123321</UniqueID>
          <Streetno>6</Streetno>
          <Street>Athol Park</Street>
          <State>WA</Street>
          <Country>AU</Street>
        </AddressRef>
      </AllAddressRef>
  </Employee>

</Company>
```

How can replace `<AddressRef>` associated to its unique identifier in `<AllAddressRef>`

```
<Address>

<Streetno>6</Streetno>
  <Street>Athol Park</Street>
  <State>WA</Street>
  <Country>AU</Street>

 </Address>
```

I am using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of // to search throughout the whole document and predicates [] to select only elements that comply to some condition.

Example:

```
<xsl:template match="AddressRef">
  <xsl:variable name="address" select="//AllAddressRef/AddressRef[UniqueID = current()]" />
  <Address>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$address/*[not(self::UniqueID)]" />
  </Address>
</xsl:template>
```